# how to use previouspage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform (log and work) , in log form , i have a textbox where the user put his username to connect. 
I want to display the username in work form, that's why i use previouspage , but always the result is null

Here is my code

in source page i used the get method

```
 public string username_connect
     { get 
        { return username.text;}
     }
```

in destination page :

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/log.aspx" %>
```

and in the loadform :

```
 label.Text = PreviousPage.username_connect;
```

get is always null

Comment: Seems that `username_connect` mixes the syntax of methods and properties.

Comment: where are you setting property username_Connect? Does  username.text contain some value.? Where is this property defined?

Comment: @iGod yes ,username.text contain value , and i defined property in log form